# Is there an easy way to setup a link seam with Visual Studio 2010's build system?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I used to have a static library which was imported by both my main program and my tests. However, I needed global variables inside of my static library to be constructed, and there's no way to force Visual Studio to do that.

What I'd like to do then is to have a project which compiles all the common C++ files, a project which compiles and links the unit tests (with the common C++ files), and a project which links the actual application.

How can I do this in Visual Studio 2010?

EDIT: Because clarification has been asked, here's what I mean:

InterfaceIUse.hpp

```
#include <memory>

struct IInterface
{
    virtual ~IInterface() {}
    virtual void SomethingIDependOn() = 0;
};

std::auto_ptr<IInterface> FactoryMethod();
```

CodeUnderTest.cpp

```
#include "InterfaceIUse.hpp"

void FunctionUnderTest()
{
    //Blah blah blah
}
```

IExistOnlyInTheMainProgram.cpp

```
#include "InterfaceIUse.hpp"

std::auto_ptr<IInterface> FactoryMethod()
{
    //I return the real implementation of the interface.
}
```

IExistOnlyInTheTest.cpp

```
#include "InterfaceIUse.hpp"

std::auto_ptr<IInterface> FactoryMethod()
{
    //I return the mock implementation of the interface.
}
```

The idea is to compile the right .cpp implementation of the given factory, which will allow the dependencies of the code to be tested to be dependency injected.

Doing this kind of link seam is easy with makefiles -- but makefiles are undesirable because I'm forced to manually maintain header dependencies in the makefile.

Comment: File->new project...  Right click->Add existing item.

Comment: Did you try creating a makefile project, and providing commands to build, link, and whatever? You can pretty much do any crazy stuff with it.

Comment: Not sure if I see the question.  Referencing the same source code files in multiple projects isn't much of a problem beyond the hassle of keeping them in sync.  You may have to change the "Object File Name" setting if the .obj files stomp each other.  I'd focus on the initialization problem, you shouldn't have one.  A little static C++ class instance variable can do wonders.

Comment: @Hans + @Noah: The problem with that is you end up compiling everything twice. It's not it's impossible (in fact, it's what I'm doing now), but waiting for everything to build twice stinks. @Gene: No -- I'd rather avoid creating a makefile project if possible (but will do so if it becomes necessary).

Comment: This is still an XY problem.  You're asking about Y without explaining the *real* X problem.

Comment: @Hans: I have a bunch of code that I have as both an application and that I'd like to test. I used to put that code into a static library, and then just link the static library into the main and test programs. However, global variables do not have their constructors run in static libraries, unless the object file containing the item in question is referenced from outside the library. This is listed in the [google test documentation](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_5_Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users) as well as [Microsoft Connect](http://bit.ly/g7mGeS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done similar setup in VS2008, which I think still applicable for you in VS2010.

To start, I setup my project hierarchy as **Build**, **ProductionCodeBase** and **TestCodeBase**.
Common interface/headers are extracted into folder accessible by all projects.

Then in my "Build" project, I manually add object file(s) from **ProductionCodeBase** into "**Release**" configuration, and object file(s) from **TestCodeBase** into "**Debug**" configuration.

Don't forget to set project dependencies so that object file are valid when linking in "**Build**".

Do note that you can create project that only compile source code into object files without attempt to link them. Just go to "Tool Build Order" for that particular project and disable corresponding linker.

Comment: Looks like it's part of the `.rules` file system which was removed in VS2010.

Comment: I just put the code in a static library (to avoid linking) and then add the object files to the other projects manually.